# Linq To SQL: Why is disposing and recreating a DataContext way faster than refreshing it?

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-sql, optimization

I noticed that disposing and re-creating a DataContext is way faster than refreshing it with `RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues`, which should effectively be the same.

While this causes my application to spike at 100% CPU for several seconds

```
dbc.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, dbc.Property);
```

the following code doesn't even eat up 50% of CPU and takes approximately a single second:

```
dbc.Dispose();
dbc = new PropertyManagementDataContext();
```

while also overwriting all my local changes and just updating my local data from the DB. Or did I overlook something?

Is there any danger to dispose and re-create the DataContext in order to get the latest data from the Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh() is actually round-tripping to the database.  Disposing and recreating the context is using locally cached connection info.  This will be faster.

Edit:
Also, according to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.refresh.aspx) you're probably using Refresh() for the wrong reason. See the remark toward the bottom.